# Does graphdb support rdf-star syntax?

Tags: graphdb, rdf-star

Consider example2 from the W3C's RDF* specification:
https://w3c.github.io/rdf-star/cg-spec/editors_draft.html

```
@prefix :    <http://www.example.org/> .

:employee38
    :familyName "Smith" ;
    :jobTitle "Assistant Designer" {| :accordingTo :employee22 |} .

# this is equivalent to:
#
# :employee38
#     :familyName "Smith" ;
#     :jobTitle "Assistant Designer" .
# << :employee38 :jobTitle "Assistant Designer" >> :accordingTo :employee22 .
```

But when I tried in GraphDB, it didn't support the former syntax, and the latter did.
Whether graphdb does not support  syntax like {|... |} ?

Comment: given that the syntax is still changing, I doubt that any SPARQL engine will adapt those changes each time and wait until the specs are stable or even an recommendation or part of RDF 1.2

Answer (score 1):

Currently GraphDB currently doesn't support syntax like {|..|}. We've adopted the embedded triples approach, but it's something we think should think of for the future release.