# How bind values within RDF-star triples to variables?

Tags: sparql, rdf, knowledge-graph, rdf-star

Using RDF-star, say I have:

```
?couple :isA :Couple .
```

and `?couple` takes values such as this one:

```
<< :Bill :marriedTo :Mary >> :isA :Couple .
```

Is there any way to extract `:Bill` and `:Mary` from the triples variable `?couple`, and bind them to variables `?husband` and `?wife`?

I know I could do this:

```
<< ?husband :marriedTo ?wife >> :isA :Couple .
```

but I also want the variable `?couple` and have this linked to `?husband` and `?wife`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to create `?couple` from its constituents:

```
<< ?husband :marriedTo ?wife >> :isA :Couple .
BIND(<< ?husband :marriedTo ?wife >> AS ?couple)
```

There is no difference between a triple constructed in this way and the `?couple` from your original example.

Another possibility is to introduce a zero-length property path between `?couple` and another node:

```
?couple :isA :Couple .
?couple <about:invalid>? << ?husband :marriedTo ?wife >> .
```

Since there is most likely no triple using `about:invalid` as the predicate, the subject will have to match the object.

Comment: Thanks! The first example is most intuitive to me, and I had no idea one could use empty property paths like in your second example! So two learnings in one.

Answer (score 2):

There are functions to access the components of a quoted triple:

```
  ?couple :isA :Couple .
  BIND(subject(?couple) AS ?husband)
  BIND(object(?couple) AS ?wife)
```

gives

```
--------------------------------------------------
| couple                       | husband | wife  |
==================================================
| << :Bill :marriedTo :Mary >> | :Bill   | :Mary |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks, wish I could accept both answers.

Comment: Could it be that these functions are not supported by Ontotext's GraphDB?

Comment: They are in the Community Report - I'm not sure what the status of RDF-star in GraphDB is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67835525/does-graphdb-support-rdf-star-syntax

Comment: Thanks, this explains why my earlier attempts to use ```{|..|}``` syntax didn't work.

Comment: Looks like what was missing here was the prefix for the functions. At least in GraphDB the functions are called as rdf:subject and rdf:object.

Comment: Thanks for the information. They are keywords in SPARQL-star report https://www.w3.org/2021/12/rdf-star.html but things take time to get through the technology pipeline.

Comment: I may note that I'm using GraphDB 9.11. Perhaps this has already been fixed in GraphDB 10, which was released a couple of months ago.